# Google glass sample video

Tags: video-recording

I would like to make a video showing a possible interaction with Google glass. I have worn it once and don't even have one.

What I am thinking now is to use

an iphone 3d printed headmount attachment with gopro headmount

I want the video to be as natural as possible (that it looks like shot from a glass close to eyes)
example:

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: It sounds like you know what you want. What's the question??

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a little more detail about what you are expecting as an answer.

Comment: It looks like he is asking for suggestions on gear that feels like you are wearing google glass. I mean I would just go with gopro head attachment and record.

Answer (score 2):

There's several techniques you can use to emulate Google Glass' eyesight videos. The next best thing would probably be to buy a pair of camera (sun-)glasses. Judging by what you're trying to achieve, your best option is to buy any camera from [pivothead](http://pivothead.com/), they all film full-HD 30fps video. Other options include the [SunnyCam Glasses](http://sunnycamglasses.com/) and the [iVUE Camera Glasses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CB25RCQ). There's also the [Zeal HD Goggles](http://www.zealhd.com/), but those are probably impractical in temperate environments.

Alternatives include the [GoPro Hero 3](http://gopro.com/cameras) (Head-mounted camera, as you suggested), the [ContourROAM2](http://contour.com/products/contourroam2) (Waterproof) and the [Braun SixZero](http://www.braun-phototechnik.de/en/products/detail/~id.908/BRAUN-SIXZERO-Digital-Video-Camera.html) (or any other head/helmet-mounted camera). If you're on a tight budget you might want to manufacture some sort of head-mounted camera yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have Glass and the camera isn't that great, so you could probably just duct tape your iPhone (in a case so it doesnt get sticky junk all over it) straight the the plastic part of the gopro headmount, and you'd have a better camera.